# Python - Time series split indexes automatically for several categories

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary, time-series

I am doing a time-series split and I want to create a list of train and text indexes for each split, by category.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4], 'prod': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'd'], 'cat': ['c1', 'c2', 'c1', 'c2', 'c2', 'c1', 'c2', 'c2', 'c2', 'c1']})
df
date prod cat
1    a    c1 
1    b    c2 
2    a    c1 
2    b    c2 
2    c    c2 
3    a    c1 
3    b    c2 
3    c    c2 
4    b    c2 
4    d    c1 

time_split = [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I was able to create a list of lists with the indexes for each train-test split, but I also want to create test indexes automatically for each category. Manually the code is the following:

```
train_index = []
test_index = []
cat1_index = []
cat2_index = []

for i in range(3):
    idx = df.loc[df['date'] < time_split[i]].index
    idx2 = df.loc[(df['date'] >= time_split[i]) & (df['date'] < time_split[i + 1])].index

    idx3 = df.loc[(df['date'] >= time_split[i]) & (df['date'] < time_split[i + 1])].query('cat == "c1"').index
    idx4 = df.loc[(df['date'] >= time_split[i]) & (df['date'] < time_split[i + 1])].query('cat == "c2"').index

    train_index.append(idx)
    test_index.append(idx2)
    cat1_index.append(idx3)
    cat2_index.append(idx4)
```

The problem is that I have several categories, and as the code is parametrized for several markets, the number of categories in each run is different.

Comment: Maybe this is an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem): could it be that you need the splits and not the indexes? Sci-kit has a [splitting function](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) that allows you to stratify based on a label.

Comment: I know the function, but it doesnt solve the problem. As I said, the problem is not making the splits, but doing them for n categories, where n may be different in each run.